# How can I access pictures/text on a website and display them with Tkinter?

Tags: python, web-services, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write a Python 3.x program that accesses data (pictures, text, etc.) from a website. I'd also like to display that data in a Tkinter GUI.

BTW, I'm using Python 3.4 on Windows.

Comment: I can't imagine why it wouldn't be possible. What have you tried? What part is giving you difficulty?

Comment: @dylrei I haven't been able to try anything. I am currently learning Python and don't know what modules can do what. I have done some research on what I asked, but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: `urllib.urlretrieve()`

Comment: Sounds like you want to be able to use python to browse to a page where your video/image/text is presented for streaming etc. rather than downloading and displaying from a hard drive(which would obviously take much longer). Is that right? Or do you want to actually download the info for use?

Comment: @Totem Yes, that's correct! I just want to stream it to their PC. The total size of the information and pictures would be to large to distribute in a file.

Comment: Perhaps you could simply browse the correct page, and stream a video or view the image etc. with the browser full screened. There are python modules for dealing with browsers in detail, such as mechanize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading with `urllib` and use the `Pillow` fork of `PIL` to process images:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
import urllib

# initialize window

root = Tk()
root.geometry('640x480')

# retrieve and download image

location = 'https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-logo.png'
image = open('image.png', 'wb')
image.write(urllib.urlopen(location).read())
image.close()

# create canvas for drawing

canvas = Canvas(root, width = 640, height = 480)
canvas.place_configure(x = 0, y = 0, width = 640, height = 480)

# load image with PIL and draw to canvas

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = 'image.png')
canvas.create_image(10, 10, image = image, anchor = NW)

# start program

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For 3.x, use the pillow fork of PIL.  (It is not a bad choice for 2.7 either.)  3.4 on Windows comes with tcl/tk 8.6, whose PhotoImage class can handle .png (as well as .bmp and .jpg usable in earlier versions also).  Pillow is compatible with PIL and imported as 'PIL', so the code posted should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Pillow.

Comment: My comment should say .gif, not .jpg.  One can use the latter by converting with pillow.  For 3.x, `urllib` should be `urllib.request`.  If one wants to use a .png exactly as downloaded, `tkinter.PhotoImage` can be used instead of PIL.ImageTk (with tcl/tk 8.6) but for tcl/tk 8.5 or for any other format (such as .jpg or .tiff) or for.png modification (resizing), PIL(low) or the equivalent is needed.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Where can I get PIL? I tried using "pip install PIL and it" didn't work. I am not sure if I am doing this wrong or not.

Comment: @AustinHargis You can install `Pillow` a more functional port of `PIL` with `pip install Pillow`.

Comment: Be sure to upvote and mark as answer Austin if you can.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi When I run this code, I get this error: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Python's `urllib` does have `urlopen`.

Answer (score -2):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget

Try wget! It is a simple web scraper that should do just what you want.